# join two files based on three columns

Tags: bash, join, awk

I have following two files, I need to join them based on the value of three columns, and if not matched print NA in the unmatched column.

```
cat f1
AAA  0  node4  Activated  Unreachable  down
AAA  1  node3  Activated  Pingable     cool

cat f2 
AAA  0  node3  XYZ  Active
```

Currently I am getting incorrect output using:

```
 awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$1;b[$2]=$2;c[$3]=$3;next} $1 in a && $2 in b &&  $3 in c{print $0}' f1 f2
AAA 0 node3 XYZ Active
```

Desired output:

```
AAA 0 node4 Activated Unreachable down NA
AAA 1 node3 Activated Pingable    cool Active
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***awk*** approach:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1,$3]=$5; next}{$7="NA";if(($1,$3) in a){$7=a[$1,$3]} print}' f2 f1
```

The output:

```
AAA 0 node4 Activated Unreachable down NA
AAA 1 node3 Activated Pingable cool Active
```

---

`a[$1,$3]=$5` - stores the value of the fifth field `$5` in the second file `f2` using combination of first `$1` and third `$3` fields as array key

`$7="NA";` - initiates an additional seventh field `$7` with default value "NA"

Answer (score 1):

Use an `Awk` logic as below,

```
awk 'FNR==NR{hash[$1FS$3]=$NF; next}{for(i in hash) if (match(i,$1FS$3)) { $(NF+1)=hash[i] } else { $(NF+1)="NA" } }1' f2 f1
```

which produces output as you needed.

```
AAA 0 node4 Activated Unreachable down NA
AAA 1 node3 Activated Pingable cool Active
```

The idea is to *parse* the second file first to store the status, index by the node value into the array `hash`. Then on the first file, a loop on all *indices* and if the value in `$3` on `f1` matches the hashed value, print the status accordingly and it not found just print `NA`.