# Join two variables based on first three columns in bash

Tags: bash, awk

I need to join two variables based on the value of first three columns, I have tried [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43512905/join-two-files-based-on-three-columns) but I am not able to figure out the solution as I could not understand how the solution was implemented so couldn't tweak the solution with new set of data.

```
x='AA   N-1 0   OPEN    WORKING REACHABLE
AA  N-1 0   OPEN    WORKING REACHABLE
AA  N-1 0   OPEN    WORKING REACHABLE
BB  N-1 0   OPEN    WORKING REACHABLE
BB  N-1 0   OPEN    WORKING REACHABLE
CC  N-1 0   OPEN    WORKING REACHABLE
DD  N-1 0   OPEN    WORKING REACHABLE'


y='AA   N-1 0   XYZ-0   PINGABLE
AA  N-1 0   XYZ-1   PINGABLE
AA  N-1 0   XYZ-2   PINGABLE
CC  N-1 0   IJK-0   NOT-PINGABLE'
```

I tried this:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1,$3]=$4; next}{$7="NA";if(($1,$3) in a){$7=a[$1,$3]} print}' <(echo "$x"|sort)  <(echo "$y"|sort)
```

and

```
   echo "$x" |while read name node location lastThree;
    do
        siLastTwo=$(echo "$y" |awk '{print $4,$5}')
        echo "$y"|awk '{NF=3}1' |grep -q  "$name $node $location" ;
            if [ $? -eq 0 ];then
                echo "$name $node $location $lastThree $siLastTwo"
            else
                echo "$name $node $location NA NA"
            fi
    done |awk 'NF==8'|column -t
```

I need to achieve something like this:

```
AA  N-1 0   OPEN    WORKING REACHABLE   XYZ-0   PINGABLE
AA  N-1 0   OPEN    WORKING REACHABLE   XYZ-1   PINGABLE
AA  N-1 0   OPEN    WORKING REACHABLE   XYZ-2   PINGABLE
BB  N-1 0   OPEN    WORKING REACHABLE   NA      NA
BB  N-1 0   OPEN    WORKING REACHABLE   NA      NA
CC  N-1 0   OPEN    WORKING REACHABLE   IJK-0   NOT-PINGABLE    
DD  N-1 0   OPEN    WORKING REACHABLE   NA      NA
```

Humble request: Please help me not just with the solution, with some explanation, as I know I should not keep asking similar questions. Thanks.

Comment: why should `XYZ-1` and `XYZ-2` become `XYZ-0` in the final result?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest: Good comment on my answer, I don't think it can be hashed then, in `$y` for same values of `AA   N-1 0` there are three different values of `$4` and `$5`

Comment: @monk: You need to introduce something uniquely identifiable key in `$y` else this is not easily possible in `Awk`(or) the line numbers of the keys should match `AA` and `CC`

Comment: @monk: but it has `XYZ-2` for first 3 values in col4 which is incorrect

Comment: I am with Inian, and am surprised people have come up with answers when there is no unique identifier between x and y??

Comment: @monk what do you think about python for this?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, excuse me for this code. I believe it's ugly, but it works (except of NA columns, but I hope you get the idea to fix it quickly).

```
echo "${x}" | while read line; do
col1="$(echo "${line}" | awk '{print $1}')"
col2="$(echo "${line}" | awk '{print $2}')"
col3="$(echo "${line}" | awk '{print $3}')"
#echo "col1: ${col1}, col2: ${col2}, col3: ${col3}"
#echo "===show matched for line: '${line}'====="
matcher="$(echo "${y}" | awk -v col1="${col1}" -v col2="${col2}" -v col3="${col3}" '($1 == col1) && ($2 == col2) && ($3 == col3) {$1=$2=$3=""; print}')"
#echo "${matcher}"
if [ -n "${matcher}" ]; then
    echo "${matcher}" | while read mtch; do
        res="${line}${mtch}"
        echo ${res}
    done
else
    echo ${line}
fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterating all the lines and matching using regex

```
x=('AA   N-1 0   OPEN    WORKING REACHABLE'
'AA  N-1 0   OPEN    WORKING REACHABLE'
'AA  N-1 0   OPEN    WORKING REACHABLE'
'BB  N-1 0   OPEN    WORKING REACHABLE'
'BB  N-1 0   OPEN    WORKING REACHABLE'
'CC  N-1 0   OPEN    WORKING REACHABLE'
'DD  N-1 0   OPEN    WORKING REACHABLE')


y=('AA   N-1 0   XYZ-0   PINGABLE'
'AA  N-1 0   XYZ-1   PINGABLE'
'AA  N-1 0   XYZ-2   PINGABLE'
'CC  N-1 0   IJK-0   NOT-PINGABLE')

filter='(\w{2}\s+\S{3}\s+\w)\s+(.*)'

if [ ! -z output.log ]; then
    rm output.log
fi

touch output.log

for ((i = 0; i < ${#x[@]}; i++)) do
    x_a=${x[$i]}

    y_matched=0

    for ((j = 0 ; j < ${#y[@]}; j++ )) do
        y_a=${y[$j]}

        if [[ $x_a =~ $filter ]]; then
            x_prefix=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
            x_suffix=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}

            if [[ $y_a =~ $filter ]]; then

                y_prefix=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}    
                y_suffix=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}

                if [[ $x_prefix == $y_prefix ]] ; then
                    if ! grep "$x_prefix $x_suffix $y_suffix" output.log > /dev/null ; then
                        echo "$x_prefix $x_suffix $y_suffix" >> output.log
                    fi  
                    y_matched=1
                    continue
                fi  
            fi  
        fi  
    done    

    if [ $y_matched -ne 1 ]; then
        echo "$x_a NA  NA" >> output.log
    fi  

done
```

Had to convert the `x` and `y` to array, Im sure you can find a way to do the same if it was a single string

Comment: You get an additional line amongst the AA's and you make the assumption that the items in x and y are to match in the same order in each file.

Comment: yeah, didn't identify that the duplicate entries has to be omitted. So edited the answer to satisfy that requirement. filter for `x` and `y` were set to the same since the requirement was specifically said so. If the patters differ for `x` and `y`, two filters can be used

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '{k=$1 FS $2 FS $3}
         NR==FNR {a[k,++c[k]]=$4 OFS $5; next}
                 {if((k,++d[k]) in a) print $0, a[k,d[k]]; 
                  else print $0, "NA", "NA"} '  <(echo "$y") <(echo "$x") | 
column -t
```

will generate

```
AA  N-1  0  OPEN  WORKING  REACHABLE  XYZ-0  PINGABLE
AA  N-1  0  OPEN  WORKING  REACHABLE  XYZ-1  PINGABLE
AA  N-1  0  OPEN  WORKING  REACHABLE  XYZ-2  PINGABLE
BB  N-1  0  OPEN  WORKING  REACHABLE  NA     NA
BB  N-1  0  OPEN  WORKING  REACHABLE  NA     NA
CC  N-1  0  OPEN  WORKING  REACHABLE  IJK-0  NOT-PINGABLE
DD  N-1  0  OPEN  WORKING  REACHABLE  NA     NA
```

Comment: Can you please help me with some explanation ?